# Redux: State is updating but UI not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

My `actions`, `reducers` are all working fine. Even the state is updated in the `redux-dev-tools` and console. But these are not being rendered on the UI. Aren't the state changes to be automatically picked up by `redux` and `re-rendered`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-dewdney-u66j2

```
import "./styles.css";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { incrementCount, reducer } from "./reducer";

export default function App() {
  const store = createStore(reducer);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {store.getState().value}
      <button onClick={()=> store.dispatch(incrementCount(1))}>Increment Count</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't want to use `react-redux` and `useSelector` after which it starts working

Comment: `Aren't the state changes to be automatically picked up by redux and re-rendered`. No, absolutely not. Redux knows nothing about React and render logic. That's handled by the `Provider` in `react-redux`.

Comment: Even just adding `Provider` won't work, I need to `useSelector`. also isn't `react-redux` just optional?

Comment: Right, of course the Provider alone won't work, that's like using context without consuming it. `react-redux` _is_ optional because redux is indifferent to where you use it (react, vue, vanilla, node, etc) but I'd pretty strongly recommend using `react-redux` for react projects

Comment: Isn't there a simple way to tell react ok `re-render()`, I can put this in a `subscribe` method. How can I achieve the same without using `react-redux`? just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a store, and it's a variable holding some functionalities. So currently React actually doesn't know it, even going through the reducer and action.

React only knows something, in the function component case, a prop or a state.

```
  const Title = ({ passMeAProp }) => {
    const [createAState, dispatch ] = useState()
    ...
  }
```

If not, React doesn't know anything, because all the render is triggered by  the `dispatch` (after the first render).

So `store.dispatch` does resolve the store data, but someone needs to notify the React this is done, thus `useSelctor`.

FYI, most of  the store related stuff has nothing to do with React, thus the name `react-redux`. This is from the documentation.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {
  decrement,
  increment,
  incrementByAmount,
  incrementAsync,
  selectCount,
} from './counterSlice'
import styles from './Counter.module.css'

export function Counter() {
  const count = useSelector(selectCount)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          aria-label="Increment value"
          onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}
        >
          +
        </button>
        <span className={styles.value}>{count}</span>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          aria-label="Decrement value"
          onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}
        >
          -
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* omit additional rendering output here */}
    </div>
  )
}
```